# How to add a listener to the ios keyboard Backspace Button

Tags: ios, events, delegates, keyboard, listener

In my iOS app i have 4 input pins X-X-X-X and what i want is if the user taps backspace, the value of my pin box will be deleted in an order from right to left.

Comment: we are not predict your code and your used method please attech your code with question so other can see and give answer related/

Comment: Are you using a button for the backspace or is it on the default keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by showing a custom keyboard if the iOS version is 8.1 and 8.2. Those version have bugs on backspace. See my custom keyboard on github: https://github.com/rhonnel/iOS-Custom-Keyboard.git